# How to reject Rails update method and trigger JavaScript alert box?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I've `update` method inside my controller:

```
def update
    if @daily_order.update(daily_order_params.merge({default_order:false}))
        respond_to :js
    else
        render :edit
    end     
end
```

I've `pax` as one of the params inside the `daily_order_params` and what I'm trying to do now is, I want to show a JS alert when user is trying to update a daily order with zero (`0`) `pax` value.

I try to use byebug inside that `update` method to check `params[:pax]` but it returns nothing. It's blank.

[image]

But the newly updated `pax` value was saved successfully inside the database.

[image]

I try to use `before_update` inside my model, but I didn't know how to move forward.

```
before_update   :reject_zero_pax_order_update

def reject_zero_pax_order_update
    # i got stucked here
end
```

**update.js.erb**

```
console.log("record updated");
```

What should I do to:

1. Reject the update if the entered `pax` is `0`
2. Trigger a JS alert box if the entered `pax` is `0`
3. Maintain the old `pax` inside the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :pax attribute is inside the :daily_order hash not inside the params hash. 
Your params looks something like this:

```
{ daily_order: { pax: 0 }}
```

hence you should access it with  `params[:daily_order][:pax]`

Your action should look something like this :

```
unless params[:daily_order][:pax] == 0
  @daily_order.update(daily_params.merge{default_order: false} )
  respond_to :js
else
  render :edit
end
```

#update.js.erb

```
alert('hey, the pax cant be 0 ');
```

I am assuming, you want the update to take place only when the pax is present else show the alert.

Comment: Thanks Ajay! Very helpful. :D

Answer (score 0):

For displaying alert box for pax value can't be equal to 0, you need to add id or class on both update button and pax field. Also you have to add hidden field for getting id of current daily order which is to be updated.

```
# Add hidden field:
<%= hidden_field_tag "daily_order_id", @daily_order.id %>

# Add id on pax field:
<%= f.text_field :pax, id: 'daily_order_pax' %>

# Add id on update button:
<%= f.submit 'Update', id: 'update_daily_order' %>
```

Then add following code in js file:-

```
$(document).on('click', '#update_daily_order', function(event) {
    event.preventdefault();
    var id = $('#daily_order_id').val();
    var pax_value = $('#daily_order_pax').val();
    if (pax_value == 0) {
        alert("pax value can't be equal to 0");
    }else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: '/daily_orders/' + id
            data: $('#form_id').serialize();
        });
    }
});
```

Above ajax will call only when pax value is not equal to 0